# Error: Failed to Write, Broken Pipe when running python script on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm new to cloud computing in general, and I've started a free trial with Amazon's Web Services, in hopes of using their EC2 servers to run some code for Kaggle competitions. I'm currently working on running a test Python script for doing some image processing and testing a linear classifier (I don't suspect these details are relevant to my problem, but wanted to provide some context).

Here are the steps I've gone through to run my script on an EC2 instance:

1. Log in to AWS, and start EC2 instance where I've installed relevant Python modules for my tasks (e.g. Anaconda distribution). As a sidenote, all my data and the script I want to run are in the same directory on this server instance.
2. SSH to my EC2 instance from my laptop, and `cd` to the directory with my script.
3. Run `screen` to run program in background.
4. Run script via `python program.py` and detach from screen session (`ctrl + A, D`)
5. Keep EC2 instance running, but exit from SSH session connecting my laptop to the server.

I've followed these steps a number of times, which result in either (a) "Broken Pipe" errors, or (b) in an error where the connection appears to "hang". In the case of (b), I've attempted to disconnect from the SSH session and reconnect to the server, however I am unable to do so due to an error stating "connection has been reset by peer".

I'm not sure if I need to configure something differently on the EC2 instance, or if I need to specify different options when connecting to the server via SSH. Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks for reading.

**EDIT:** I've been successful in running some example scripts using scikit-learn by setting up an iPython notebook, launching it with nohup, and running the code in a notebook cell. However, when trying to do the same with my Kaggle competition code, the same "hanging" issue happens, and the connection appears to be dropped, causing the code to stop running. The image dataset I'm running the code on in the second case is quite a bit larger than the dataset processed by the example code in the first case. Not sure if dataset size along is causing the issue, or how to solve this.